Endomorphisms of a Finite Field
Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be the finite field with $q$ elements, where $q$ is a power of a prime $p$. Define the dual of $\mathbb{F}_q$, denoted $\mathbb{F}_q^*$, to be the set of endomorphisms of $\mathbb{F}_q$, endowed with a ring structure in the usual way. Is $\mathbb{F}_q$ isomorphic as a field to $\mathbb{F}_q^*$?
The question arose as I noticed that if the Frobenius map $\mathrm{Frob}_p:x\mapsto x^p$ generates $\mathbb{F}_q^*$ as a module over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, then the number of endomorphisms would be finite and would be $q$, as $(\mathrm{Frob}_p)^n$ is the identity map on $\mathbb{F}_q$.
Edit: Thank you for replies. After thinking over this, I've realised I did a stupid, as Will has pointed out: you cannot add two field endomorphisms, and so you only get a group structure under composition, instead of a ring structure. This lead me to the follow-up question, is the dual isomorphic to the cyclic group of order $n$, generated by $\mathrm{Frob}_p$?
Clarification: I am talking about the set of functions $f:\mathbb{F}_q\to\mathbb{F}_q$ such that $$f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b),$$ $$f(a-b)=f(a)-f(b),$$ $$f(ab)=f(a)f(b),$$ $$f(a/b)=f(a)/f(b), b\neq0, f(b)\neq0$$

As is well known (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Frobenius_automorphism_and_Galois_theory), the field endomorphisms = automorphisms of $\mathbb F_q$ form a cyclic group of order $d=[\mathbb F_q:\mathbb F_p]$ generated by the Frobenius, where $q=p^d$.

It is not clear what you mean by "endomorphisms".
As sl_09 points out, there are too many $\mathbb F_p$-module endomorphisms to be isomorphic to $\mathbb F_q$, and not enough ring endomorphisms. In fact ring endomorphisms do not naturally form a ring, since the sum of two ring endomorphisms is not a ring endomorphism for any nonzero ring (with unit).
There are other definitions available.
For any commutative ring $R$, the endomorphisms of $R$ as an $R$-module are naturally isomorphic to $R$. But the Frobenius map is not a $\mathbb F_q$-module endomorphism of $\mathbb F_q$, so this can't be what you mean.
One can also simply consider the algebra of $\mathbb F_p$-module endomorphisms of $\mathbb F_q$ generated by Frobenius. As you note, Frobenius has multiplicative order $n$, and the identity endomorphism has additive order $p$, so this algebra is a quotient of $\mathbb F_p[F]/(F^n-1)$. In fact, it is not hard to check that this algebra is isomorphic to $\mathbb F_p[F]/(F^n-1)$. Hence it has $p^n=q$ elements. However, it is never isomorphic to $\mathbb F_q$ unless $n=1$ since the polynomial $F^n-1$ is a multiple of $F-1$ and hence is not irreducible unless $n=1$.

Since $\mathbb{F}_q$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$ there will be $p^{n^2}$ module endomorphisms, so they are not isomorphic. If you meant ring endomorphisms, then already $\mathbb{F}_p$ has only the trivial endomorphism, so it is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_p^*$.
